# path to an audio file in resources folder in Xcode swift

Tags: swift, resources

In swift how can I get the file path for a test audio File that i have copied into the resources folder in Xcode

The code I have gives file not found. Am I looking in the right Directories with NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains? Any help much appreciated!

```
        let name = "test.wav"
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        let filePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)
        let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(filePath)) {
            print("found .wav")
        } else {
            print("file not found")
        }
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `paths` and step to `checkValidation` are all of the variables valid? If you are using simulator, try navigating to that path in Finder to see if the file is actually there.

Comment: the path generated is not to the where the Xcode resources are stored. The resources folder appears to be at users/user/appname/test.wav, but i don't see how to get the path to pick that up? When the app is installed on a device where are the files that are in Xcode stored?

Answer (score 1):

i just found this that works.

```
let name = "test.wav"  
let soundPath = (NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)
let soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath)
```